# How to covert .cshtml to .aspx

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm facing a problem when the same code at the .cshtml change to .aspx can't run in visual studio. How should I change any format or the coding for the run at .aspx? This a chatroom coding

```js
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $chats = $('#chats'),
                chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;

            chatHub.client.gotMessage = function (nickname, message) {
                $chats.append('<li><span class="label label-primary">' + htmlEncode(nickname)+'</span>' + htmlEncode(message));
                $chats.scrollTop($chats.innerHeight());
            };

            var htmlEncode = function (content) {
                return $('<div />').text(content).html();
            }

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#ctrl button").click(function (evt) {
                    var $name = $("#nickname"),
                        name = $name.val(),
                        $message = $("#message"),
                        message = $message.val();

                    chatHub.server.sendMessage(name, message);

                    $message.val("").focus();
                });
            });

            $(window)
                .resize(function () {
                    var h = Math.max(200, screen.availHeight - $chats.offset().top - 200);
                    $chats.height(h);
        })
            .resize();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no tag called section in ASP.NET webforms. So basically you could just remove the section tag.

In webforms you can use ContentPlaceholders like this, Masterpage:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="scripts" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And in any site using the masterpage:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="scripts" Runat="Server">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $chats = $('#chats'),
                chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;

            chatHub.client.gotMessage = function (nickname, message) {
                $chats.append('<li><span class="label label-primary">' + htmlEncode(nickname)+'</span>' + htmlEncode(message));
                $chats.scrollTop($chats.innerHeight());
            };

            var htmlEncode = function (content) {
                return $('<div />').text(content).html();
            }

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#ctrl button").click(function (evt) {
                    var $name = $("#nickname"),
                        name = $name.val(),
                        $message = $("#message"),
                        message = $message.val();

                    chatHub.server.sendMessage(name, message);

                    $message.val("").focus();
                });
            });

            $(window)
                .resize(function () {
                    var h = Math.max(200, screen.availHeight - $chats.offset().top - 200);
                    $chats.height(h);
        })
            .resize();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```